# Android - how to get resource by button tag?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have 8 buttons in my Activity and 8 small audios in the `res/raw` directory. When one button is clicked, the app plays the audio associated with that particular button. I named each audio the same / similar to the associated button's tag. I want to have only one method in my activity that solves all cases.

This is what I have so far :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void playPhrase(View view){

        if(view.getTag().toString().equals("doYouSpeak")){
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doyouspeakenglish);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        else if(view.getTag().toString().equals("goodEvening")){
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.goodevening);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        // the other 6 cases

    }
}
```

Is there a way to access the audios using the associated button tag (or id or anyhow) without the whole if/else statements ? Something like :

```
public void playPhrase(View view){
    String tag = view.getTag().toString();
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tag); 
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getIdentifier() method to get the id by String name.

```
String tag = view.getTag().toString();    
Int id = getResources().getIdentifier(tag, "raw", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(this, id);
mediaPlayer.start();
```